# How to wait after UiTextFiled was changed?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, delay

Every time when UITextField has been changed I send request to API using callback like:

```
keywordsField.addTarget(self, action:"keywordsChanged:", forControlEvents:.EditingChanged);



func keywordsChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        self.foundCountNumLabel.hidden = true
        self.foundCountLabel.hidden = true

        let keywords: String = sender.text!
        let urlKw = keywords.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

        self.apiUri = "&keywords=" + urlKw
        self.getData() // this function send request to API
    }
```

The problem is that app sends request even user was typed just one symbol.

So, I have many request to my API every second.

The question is how to do one request after 1 second when user stops typing?

Comment: Eugene, Use a different API; read a tutorial. http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/ I won't vote you down, but this question is too easily answered really.

Comment: Keep a timer.  When the user types, invalidate the last timer and schedule a new one.  When the timer expires, make your API request.  Each keystroke should be canceling the previous timer.